# Calling Data in R using a variable in a loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several data frames and want to process them in a loop. So I try to call the frames using a variable containing the name of the frame. How can I use a variable to address a data frame? Or in general the content of a variable as an expression?

```
# 38 data frames all named ExperimentX, with X 1:38
for(i in 1:38) {
  nextDataFrame <- paste0("Experiment",i)
  Collection$paste0("Experiment",i) <- nextDataFrame
}
```

I understand why this code doesn't work, but I have no idea how to do this in another way. Same problem with `ggplot`, where I would like to call nextExperiment in `geom_line()`, fails with the error

> ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class character.

How do I tell it to use as expression what the expression is pointing to?

```
Plot1 <- ggplot()
ToDo <- c(1, 5, 3) # specifies dataframes to plot
counter <- length(ToDo)
while (counter!=0) {
  NumberOfDataframe <- ToDo[counter]
  nextExperiment <- paste0("Experiment", NumberOfDataframe)
  Plot1 + geom_line(data = nextExperiment, aes(x = Position_mm, y = Force_N)))
  counter <- counter - 1
}
```

(This is my first post.)

Comment: Perhaps you should first think about doing this another way. In your `ggplot` code the `geom_line` function suggests all the `data.frame` are the same. In which case you should really append them into a single data.frame e.g. `bind_rows` with an additional ID column marking which experiment they come from e.g. column ID with values X1:X38. Your `geom_line` code then just needs an added `aes(..., group = ID)` or `aes(.., colour = ID` to add new data lines for each experiment. I hope that is simpler for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used several functions to solve my problem, the central finding being `get():`

> How do I tell it to use as expression what the expression is pointing to?

`get(x)` does exactly that, it calls what x is pointing to.

`paste0()` will only work if the function expects a string, but you can build the string using variables `paste0("exp", i, ".csv")`.

`assign(string_var, read.csv())` was also useful in batch creating dataframes from csv files in a loop.

```
# Batch import of range or chosen x.csv, x = 1,2,..
ToDo <- c(1:38)
for (i in 1:length(ToDo)) {
  nextFileNr <- ToDo[i]
  filePath <- paste0("Instron Daten/", nextFileNr, ".csv")
  if (ToDo[i] < 10) {  # produce exp01,.. for better sorting with ls()
    ExpName <- paste0("exp0", nextFileNr)
  } else {
      ExpName <- paste0("exp", nextFileNr)
  }
  # assign(obj_with_name_contained, be_filled_with_content_of_this)
  assign(ExpName, read.csv2(filePath, header = TRUE, skip = 53))
}

# Delete unwanted coloumns in all data frames using loop and get()
for(i in 1:length(ToDo)) {
  if (ToDo[i] < 10) {  # if exp1 make it exp01
    tempPattern <- paste0("exp0",i)
  } else {
    tempPattern <- paste0("exp",i)
  }
  set(get(tempPattern), j = 6L, value = NULL)  # delete col 6
}

# Tare measurement by shifting values with mean of first 1500 entries
for(i in 1:length(ToDo)) {
  if (ToDo[i] < 10) {
    tempPattern <- paste0("exp0",i)
  } else {
    tempPattern <- paste0("exp",i)
  }
  meanValue <- mean(get(tempPattern)[0:1500,"Kraft_N"])
  for(i in 1:nrow(get(tempPattern))) {
    set(get(tempPattern), j = "Kraft_N", i = i, value = (get(tempPattern)$Kraft_N[i] - meanValue))
  }
}

# Batch place all in a list
listFW <- mget(ls(pattern = "exp"))
```

And concerning ggplot: adding layers in a loop does seem not work. Data has to be combined before calling ggplot. Used `bind_rows` as recommended:

```
makeExpStrings <- function(ToDo) { # creating name strings for calling the chosen data
i <- integer(0) # initializing
chosenExpStrings <- character(0)
for (i in 1:length(ToDo)) { # get data specified in ToDo and append
  nextFileNr <- ToDo[i]
  if (ToDo[i] < 10) {  # adapting to naming scheme of data
    ExpName <- paste0("exp0", nextFileNr)
  } else {
    ExpName <- paste0("exp", nextFileNr)
  }
  chosenExpStrings<-append(chosenExpStrings, ExpName)
}
return(chosenExpStrings)
}
chosenExpStrings <- makeExpStrings(ToDo)
# combine all coloumns with identifier for coloring
combi <- bind_rows(listFW[chosenExpStrings], .id="expNr")
ggplot() + 
  geom_path(data = combi, size = 0.4, aes_string(x = "Position_mm", y = "Kraft_N", colour = "expNr"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your specific problem. As far as I understand what you are trying to do isn't recommended. You should put those `data.frame` in another R object. And then iterate in that object to do whatever you want to each experiment.

I would suggest combining the dfs in a list and then using `lapply()`

```
a = list(exp1 = data.frame(a = rnorm(100),b=rnorm(100)),
     exp2 = data.frame(a = rnorm(100),b=rnorm(100)),
     exp3 = data.frame(a = rnorm(100),b=rnorm(100)))

lapply(a,summary)
$exp1
       a                  b           
Min.   :-2.05828   Min.   :-1.91026  
 1st Qu.:-0.61256   1st Qu.:-0.80438  
 Median : 0.09998   Median :-0.09383  
 Mean   : 0.01377   Mean   :-0.07228  
 3rd Qu.: 0.72794   3rd Qu.: 0.50432  
 Max.   : 1.91998   Max.   : 2.08383  

$exp2
   a                 b          
 Min.   :-2.0764   Min.   :-2.3634  
 1st Qu.:-0.6953   1st Qu.:-0.5302  
 Median : 0.0952   Median : 0.1206  
 Mean   : 0.1227   Mean   : 0.1186  
 3rd Qu.: 0.8570   3rd Qu.: 0.6945  
 Max.   : 3.2124   Max.   : 2.4100  

$exp3
       a                  b           
 Min.   :-2.46588   Min.   :-3.43183  
 1st Qu.:-0.44548   1st Qu.:-0.75116  
 Median : 0.09448   Median : 0.04380  
 Mean   : 0.15859   Mean   :-0.02339  
 3rd Qu.: 0.84165   3rd Qu.: 0.69042  
 Max.   : 2.40169   Max.   : 2.13928
```

Comment: I will try combining them. Is there a way to loop and iterate instead of explicitly adding exp1, exp2,... expN?

Comment: Found get(), works nice. a <- list(get(ls(pattern = "exp"))